# Replaying a Charles proxy session and recording the results

Tags: http, proxy, request, charles-proxy

I've saved a few sessions with the splendid Charles http proxy network monitor, and I'd like to replay the requests in the sessions and save the new results. Is there any way to do this? I know I can replay a session using the Repeat command, but the requests only show up in the status bar. I need a view of the new session using the old requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh! The answer is laughably easy! You open the saved session, then create a new session, which starts recording. You switch back to the saved session and replay it.